# UIButtonBarItem not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a bottom toolbar in an iOS app the only contains one button to play / pause a live Icecast radio stream.  Everything is working except the button changing from the Play icon to the Pause icon and vice versa.  Here's my code.

```
@IBAction func PlayStop(_ sender: Any) {
        if player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            // Stop the live radio stream
            player.pause()
            // Set the radio tower image to off with Alpha 0.3
            TowerImage.image = UIImage(named: "TowerOff")
            TowerImage.alpha = 0.3
            // Set the Toolbar icon to the Play Icon
            PlayStopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.play, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.PlayStop(_:)))
        } else if player.timeControlStatus != .playing {
            // Play the live radio stream
            player.play()
            // Set the radio tower image to on with Alpha 1
            TowerImage.image = UIImage(named: "TowerOn")
            TowerImage.alpha = 1
            // Set the Toolbar icon to the Pause Icon
            PlayStopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.pause, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.PlayStop(_:)))
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var TowerImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var PlayStopButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Comment: what is `toolbarItems` you commented did you dragged `toolBar`as outlet ??

Comment: No I didn't, first iOS app, do I need to make an outlet for the toolbar as well as its items?

Comment: yes and do `self.toolBar.items = [playStopButton]` ??

Comment: Thats working, how to I add flexible containers in the dictionary to keep it in the center?

Comment: Sorted it by adding the flex space to a variable then assigning in in the dictionary, thanks man.

Comment: ok but keep in mind `items` is an array not dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to hook the toolbar as outlet then

```
let playStopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.pause, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.PlayStop(_:)))  
self.toolBar.items = [playStopButton]
```

Comment: I changed to `let PlayStopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.pause, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.PlayStop(_:)))` and
            `self.toolbarItems = [PlayStopButton]` but the nothing has changed, stream starts and stops, image changed, button stays the same